# Ruby function Rails XML builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I want to write a recursive function inside the rails xml builder. Is this possible?

Thanks, Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's an object, so you can pass it. Or even the block.

Comment: done! created a method in helper and passed xml object. problem solved! thanks a lot